# How to use my menu PHP code as sidebar?

Tags: plugins, menus, css, sidebar

I'm using the Max Mega Menu plugin. The plugin gives me a `PHP Function` for my menu. But the plugin has no documentation on how to use it.

I want to add the menu as a sidebar to the left of my existing contents. What should I do next? Should I just copy the php code to `sidebar.php` in Wordpress? What am I supposed to do with the PHP code?
How to use it in my sidebar?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) is a standard WordPress function, so you would just copy/paste that PHP code into `sidebar.php` using whatever additional arguments you need. However, since the theme has a `sidebar.php` it probably has widget areas, so I would look in `Appearance > Widgets` in the dashboard and look for a sidebar widget area.

In there, I would create a textarea widget into the sidebar widget area and copy/paste the **shortcode** into that widget. It should then render the menu in the same way as the PHP code.

Comment: This is correct. When Max Mega Menu is enabled for a location the wp_nav_menu arguments are reset to ensure they'll work with the mega menu walker and CSS output, so you just need to copy and paste the code provided.


However, if your theme has a sidebar widget area already, you just need to add the 'Max Mega Menu' widget to it and that will display the menu for you (see the 'Widget' option under Menu Display Options)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the 2 different way to show Max Mega Menu in sidebar area

1. Copy and paste the shortcode in your widget area.
2. Copy and paste the php code in sidebar.php file and place it where you want to show it.